# Coupling to Dependency Injection Frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection

### Preface

I feel like there is a real possibility to shoot yourself in the foot when working with DI frameworks.
(My framework of choice is ninject so I'll be using that in my examples.)

I'm going to step back for a second and look at the reason DI **frameworks** exists:
*To prevent having to do DI by hand*

Right so, in the spirit of Ninjects documentation, lets say we have a `Dojo` that creates `Samurai`s. These `Samurai`s are given an `IWeapon` when they are made.

```
class Samurai{
    readonly IWeapon weapon;

    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon){
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

Now it is my understanding that the `Dojo` would use `Kernel.Get<IWeapon>()` when it creates a `Samurai`.

**Woah**
Didn't I just couple my Dojo to the Kernel?
Also... How is it supposed to get the Kernel: DI, a singleton, service location?

I feel like we just swiftly defeated the purpose of DI because now I'm dependent on my DI framework. What happens if ninja's are defeated and ninject dies too?

### Question

How do we use DI without coupling to a DI framework?

#### Postface

I'm sure this question has been asked before however I couldn't find anything. Please use the comments to post relevant questions so that we can pool the knowledge to figure out the best solution.

Comment: You will not like my answer ;) : You can do DI without coupling to a DI framework if you do the DI framework by yourself. I did it once, you can implement the "strategy pattern" and do the "glueing" (how to find the piece of code to inject) by yourself (some XML file, or database table or reflection over the installation folder or whatever you want)... Or you can use Ninject.

Comment: Prism does that, you can chose to use MEF or Unity or any other DI framework. But do you really need the DI to be swappable? that sounds like overengineering.

Comment: There is **always** some coupling. Not having any coupling means you have a program that does nothing.

Comment: @Oded Touche, I am more aiming to avoid *tight* coupling to a DI

Comment: @Baboon Yes it is. But I'm sure there are valid scenarios

Comment: @Rafa Isn't that just building a DI framework... that you then couple to?

Comment: I have a bunch of blogposts that talk about this in detail: http://kozmic.pl/the-best-of/

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic can you please point to one in particular?

Comment: All three cover the various aspects of the problem. I suggest you read them in the order listed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing Dependency Injection the trick is to have all your classes inject their dependencies through the constructor. This way you can let the Kernel build up a complete object graph for you from the root object.

This 'root object' however, is something that has to be resolved directly by calling `kernel.Get<HomeController>()` (if `HomeController` is the root object). So somewhere in your application you will have to call `kernel.Get`. It's impossible to go without.

The trick is to minimize this to ideally a single line of code in the application and place this near the startup path. Probably close to the place where you registered your dependencies. The rest of the application stays oblivious to the use of any DI framework.

There are even integration packages for Ninject and other containers that allow you to remove that single line of code depending on which application platform you use. ASP.NET MVC for instance has great extendibility points that allow you to plug in a `ControllerFactory` that allows you to let that factory call `kernel.Get` for you.

> How do we use DI without coupling to a DI framework?

There will always be some coupling, but ideally this should only be the startup path. All other code should be oblivious to the use of a container. There will still be a assembly dependency, but this dependency will only exist in the startup project, and not in your business layer.

> look at the reason DI frameworks exists: To prevent having to do DI by
>   hand

To be more precise. DI helps making your application more maintainable. DI frameworks help making the startup path of your application (a.k.a. [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)) more maintainable.

Comment: I do like this approach, limiting dependency injection to an 'entry point' if you will. And since I use MVC this is even more appealing. However I do foresee a caveat, that being the entry point of the DI could become unnecessarily large. Furthermore this seems to be similar to just doing it by hand.

Comment: If your entry point becomes "unnecessarily large" you might have to take a good look at your DI configuration and the application design. Take a look at things like batch registration (perhaps with convention based configuration). This lowers the amount of code (and increases the maintainability) dramatically. It's hard to define "doing things by hand" since even without a DI container, you would probably write LINQ queries and easy helper methods to keep this place more maintainable. Post any questions here on SO and get a copy of the book "Dependency Injection in .NET". It's a life changer.

Comment: I can't recall my DI configuration to have ever become bigger than about a 100 lines of code for the biggest applications I dealt with. If you find yourself constantly changing this configuration, for the smallest changes in your application, again, take a good look at the design. There are things btw that are very hard to achieve by hand. Take for instance the proposed application design in [this article](http://bit.ly/s7tGEH) and the shown use of decorators. That's pretty awkward and maintenance heavy to do by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Service Locator design pattern considered harmful (and actually from many points of view [considered as anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)), so I strongly discourage from using it from your code.

Using Service Locator leads to unclear interface between your class (`class Dojo`) and their clients. Reading your class header would be impossible to understand required context: what should I do to use this class properly: what should I put inside what to fulfill all the requiremenets.

Actually, I prefer using another pattern called [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), when we're using container (a.k.a. Service Locator) only in one place in our application: in the root of the application, like `Main`, `HomeController` etc.

I strongly suggested to take a look at book on the topic: ["Dependency Injection in .NET"](http://manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seeman that covers all this topics in more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have some sort of abstraction to your DI container. Consider an interface like this,

```
public interface IDependencyResolver
{
    T Get<T>();
}
```

Which you then have an implementation of - for Ninject it could look like this.

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel();

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

This means you use Ninject like any other 3rd party component in your project, with the one exception of the line that reads

```
IDependencyResolver resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver();
```

Which should only be found once somewhere, depending on your needs. You then use your `IDependencyResolver` instance instead of the `IKernel` provided by Ninject (or similar containers for other frameworks).

To switch DI container is then just a matter of implementing a new `IDependencyResolver`.

Comment: And what does that solve? Instead of using the kernel as service locator, you use this `IDependencyResolver` as service locator.

Comment: Yes, which (if done right) means no ties to any specific DI framework. It is a simple abstraction layer.

Comment: This is a fair solution, it was my initial thought. However you still have to reference the IDependencyResolver all over your application. Not a bad thing, not a good thing; somewhere in-between.